# VBA to click on href link on web page

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to click on link with has

**`<'a' href="javascript:browserPrint();" class="StaticLink">Print</a>"`**

I have tried it with tag name but not working.Tag not able to find the href

Could you please let me know how to click on href link

Comment: have you tried `Workbook.FollowHyperlink` [Link Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839280.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Show the code you have which isn't working.

Comment: Does it really have 'a' ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
ie.document.querySelector("a[href=javascript:browserPrint();]").Click
```

Targets the first element with `a` tag gaving `href` attribute with value `'javascript:browserPrint();'`